# Could not calculate the upgrade on distribution upgrade

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

I've been trying to update Ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10 through Update Manager multiple times since the release but have encountered this error every single time:

> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
>   E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
>
> This can be caused by:
>   * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
>   * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
>   * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug update-manager' in a terminal.

The apt.log contains a lot of messages similar to:

```
Investigating (8) gnome-control-center [ amd64 ] < 1:2.32.1-0ubuntu15 -> 1:3.2.0-0ubuntu6 > ( gnome )
Broken gnome-control-center:amd64 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-2 [ amd64 ] < none -> 3.2.0-0ubuntu4 > ( libs ) (>= 3.1.2)
  Considering libgnome-desktop-3-2:amd64 47 as a solution to gnome-control-center:amd64 22
  Holding Back gnome-control-center:amd64 rather than change libgnome-desktop-3-2:amd64
```

Any ideas what I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you completely up-to-date on the regular updates?

Comment: Yes, I've installed all avaliable updates, and also tried disabling all non-Ubuntu sources (PPAs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a similar issue. I then found [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859338) - removing the ia32-libs package as rockorequin suggested solved my problem.

Comment: This did the trick! Just for reference for others: This might remove a few of your applications you'll have to reinstall after the upgrade.